# How to get matching settings for cycles and vray

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am currently testing for my dissertation, I am putting cycles up against vray to gather some data, but to keep the data fair i need to set vray up to have settings that match cycles settings. Could anyone advise me on how to go about doing this correctly as information on the subject is sparse at best.

my usual cycles settings are

SAMPLING

path tracing
clamp direct 0
clamp indirect o
light sampling 0.01
render 100

LIGHT PATHS

transparency
max 4
min 1

bounces
max 4
min 1
diffuse 4
glossy 4
Transmission 4
volume 0

shadows yes
reflective/refractive caustics off

if anyone could help shed some light on how to transfer even just the sample rate to vray for either path tracing OR branched path Tracing i would be grateful
thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. Both engines are absolutely different (biased vs unbiased). You can get nearly the same result, but it depends on the scene (interior vs exterior). What's your actual goal? http://renderspud.blogspot.de/2006/10/biased-vs-unbiased-rendering.html

Comment: my goal is to see which render engine is the best route to follow for a freelance 3d artist leaving university/staring up their own studio. e.g. which is the best rout fiscally and for quality vs time consumption, based on some test scenes i have created that can be run in both software’s. Personally, i feel blender and cycles give better results and is obviously cheeper.so for a start-up freelancer it seems like a no brainer, i have managed to get consistent results with both software’s. Using settings that are roughly equal to each engines own sampling rates.

Comment: Depends on the job. Consider that rendering a sequence takes ages on cycles, which makes it expensive for freelancers. In reality one quality frame (hd) takes 20-30 minutes (one card/dual xeon cpu). That's in total for a 30 second clip (~1000 frames) on a render farm like *renderstreet* ~$1.800. Also cycles has missing features (light groups, matte objects, etc), means e.g. that you have to re-render the sequence to get a quality id pass. Vray has all that built-in, which makes it a better studio engine. For all that and more reasons freelancers are using *Redshift* nowadays. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your time on this i have taken into account what you have said, i have since looked at my collected data and see that you are indeed correct in the assumption of cycles taking much longer to render in fact the figures for both render engines are pretty poor unfortunately, i have since looked at red shift and octane,i have started to use octane and i must say i am very impressed with it ,either stand alone or with the blender plugin.

Comment: No problem. The thing is, there is no *all in one* engine. In fact, the range of jobs is too broad. However, I think there is a chance figuring out what engine is suitable for the respective task. IMHO depending on the scene, the output of Cycles is great but it lacks on features and the same applies to Octane. Redshift has all relevant features built-in but even with high level settings, the quality (e.g. the DoF) isn't the same as Cycles. For a single image I'd always recommend cycles, for vfx shots I'd prefer Mantra. For motion graphics there is a good reason to choose octane etc...